# Whats the next number in OEIS A258107? (PART I of II)

Tags: sequences-and-series, oeis

Part II is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305511/whats-the-next-number-in-oeis-a258107-part-ii-of-ii)

[OEIS LINK](https://oeis.org/A258107)

I've watched Dr James Grimes explain Why 82,000 is an extraordinary number.

I was intrigued by this sequence and disocvered the following patterns.

I was wondering if I had just discovered the "Obvious" or stumbled across a possible method to identify the next number or prove there isnt a next number.

What I discovered is as follows:-

**Base 3**

Within base 3 counterfeit binary numbers (e.g. numbers comprising of digits 1 and 0) greater that 1 always appear in pairs, e.g. 10, 11, then 100, 101 etc..
By counting the base 3 numbers that occur consecutively containing the digit 2 we see a pattern emerge, e.g. 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4 etc.

This table shows (i) The first 39 base 3 numbers (0 - 38), (ii) The counterfeit binary numbers always appear in consecutive pairs, (iii) The start of the digit 2 occurrence pattern.

```
 Decimal    Counterfeit    Digit 2    Count    
     0        0
     1        1
     2                       2          1
     3        10
     4        11
     5                       12
     6                       20
     7                       21
     8                       22         4
     9        100
    10        101
    11                       102        1
    12        110
    13        111
    14                       112
    15                       120
    16                       121
    17                       122
    18                       200
    19                       201
    20                       202
    21                       210
    22                       211
    23                       212
    24                       220
    25                       221
    26                       222        13
    27        1000
    28        1001
    29                       1002       1
    30        1010
    31        1011
    32                       1012
    33                       1020
    34                       1021
    35                       1022       4
    36        1100
    37        1101
    38                       1102
```

The base 3 pattern that's associated with the base 3 digit 2 occurrence pattern has a cycle of 64 and is as follows:-

```
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 1093,
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 3280,
```

The numbers within each line have the following properties.
The lines contain both a horizontal and vertical pattern

**Horizontal Pattern**

All odd positions within each line are 1.
The even position maximum numbers are positioned at powers of 2 from left to right e.g.

```
Position        Maximum
    2              4
    4             13
    8             40
    16           121
    32           364
    64          1093
```

The maximums are calculated

```
(3 * n) + 1, 4 = (3 * 1) + 1, 13 = (3 * 4) + 1, 40 = (3 * 13) + 1, 121 = (3 * 40) + 1, 364 = (3 * 121) + 1, 1093=(3 * 364) + 1
```

**Vertical Pattern**

The 64th number in each line follows a cyclic pattern.

```
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 1093,
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 3280,

1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 1093,
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 9841,

1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 1093,
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 3280,
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 1093,
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 29524,

1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 1093,
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 3280,
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 1093,
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 9841,
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 1093,
1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 364, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 121, 1, 4, 1, 13, 1, 4, 1, 40, 1, 4, 1, 13
```

The vertical maximums appears on Line 2, Line 4, Line 8, Line 16 etc. each maximum is calculated

```
(3 * n) + 1, 3280 = (3 * 1093) + 1, 9841 = (3 * 3280) + 1, 29524 = (3 * 9841) + 1
```

**Base 4**

As with Base 3, within base 4 counterfeit binary numbers greater that 1 always appear in pairs, e.g. 10, 11, then 100, 101 etc..
By counting the base 4 numbers that occur consecutively containing digits 2 and/or 3 we see a pattern emerge, e.g. 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10 etc.

This table shows (i) The first 39 base 4 numbers (0 - 38), (ii) The counterfeit binary numbers always appear in consecutive pairs, (iii) The start of the digits 2 and 3 occurrence pattern.

```
Decimal    Counterfeit      Digit 2 & 3        Count
0               0
1               1
2                               2
3                               3                 2
4              10
5              11
6                              12
7                              13
8                              20
9                              21
10                             22
11                             23
12                             30
13                             31
14                             32
15                             33                10
16            100
17            101
18                            102
19                            103                 2
20            110
21            111
22                            112
23                            113
24                            120
25                            121
26                            122
27                            123
28                            130
29                            131
30                            132
31                            133
32                            200
33                            201
34                            202
35                            203
36                            210
37                            211
38                            212
```

The base 4 pattern that's associated with the base 4 digits 2 and/or 3 occurrence pattern has a cycle of 64 and is as follows:-

```
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 10922,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 43690,
```

The numbers within each line have the following properties.
The lines contain both a horizontal and vertical pattern

**Horizontal Pattern**

All odd positions within each line are 2.
The even maximum numbers are positioned at powers of 2 from left to right e.g.

```
Position        Maximum
2                 10
4                 42
8                170
16               682
32              2730
64             10922
```

The maximums are calculated

```
(4 * n) + 2, 10 = (4 * 2) + 2, 42 = (4 * 10) + 2, 170 = (4 * 42) + 2, 682 = (4 * 170) + 2, 2730 = (4 * 682) + 2, 10922 = (4 * 2730) + 2
```

**Vertical Pattern**

The 64th number in each line follows a cyclic pattern.

```
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 10922,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 43690,

2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 10922,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 174762,

2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 10922,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 43690,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 10922,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 699050,

2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 10922,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 43690,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 10922,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 174762,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 10922,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 43690,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 10922,
2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2730, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 682, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 170, 2, 10, 2, 42, 2, 10, 2, 2796202
```

The maximums appears on Line 2, Line 4, Line 8, Line 16 etc. each maximum is calculated

```
(4 * n) + 2, 43690 = (4 * 10922) + 2, 174762 = (4 * 43690) + 2, 699050 = (4 * 174762) + 2, 2796202 = (4 * 699050) + 2
```

**Base 5**

As with Base 3 and 4, within base 5 counterfeit binary numbers greater that 1 always appear in pairs, e.g. 10, 11, then 100, 101 etc..
By counting the base 5 numbers that occur consecutively containing digits 2, 3 and/or 4 we see a pattern emerge, e.g. 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3 etc.

This table shows (i) The first 39 base 5 numbers (0 - 38), (ii) The counterfeit binary numbers always appear in consecutive pairs, (iii) The start of the digit 2,3 and/or 4 occurrence pattern.

```
Decimal   Counterfeit      Digit 2,3 & 4        Count
0             0
1             1
2                               2
3                               3
4                               4                 3
5            10
6            11
7                              12
8                              13
9                              14
10                             20
11                             21
12                             22
13                             23
14                             24
15                             30
16                             31
17                             32
18                             33
19                             34
20                             40
21                             41
22                             42
23                             43
24                             44                18
25         100
26         101
27                            102
28                            103
29                            104                 3
30         110
31         111
32                            112
33                            113
34                            114
35                            120
36                            121
37                            122
38                            123
```

The base 5 pattern that's associated with the base 5 digits 2, 3 and/or 4 occurrence pattern has a cycle of 64 and is as follows:-

```
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 58593,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 292968,
```

The numbers within each line have the following properties.
The lines contain both a horizontal and vertical pattern

**Horizontal Pattern**

All odd positions within each line are 3.

The even position maximum numbers are positioned at powers of 2 from left to right e.g.

```
 Position     Maximum
     2          18
     4          93
     8         468
    16        2343
    32       11718
    64       58593
```

The maximums are calculated

```
(5 * n) + 3, 18 = (5 * 3) + 3, 93 = (5 * 18) + 3, 468 = (5 * 93) + 3, 2343 = (5 * 468) + 3, 11718 = (5 * 2343)  + 3, 58593 = (5 * 11718) + 3
```

**Vertical Pattern**

The 64th number in each line follows a cyclic pattern.

```
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 58593,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 292968,

3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 58593,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 1464843,

3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 58593,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 292968,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 58593,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 7324218,

3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 58593,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 292968,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 58593,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 1464843,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 58593,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 292968,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 58593,
3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 36621093,

3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 11718, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 2343, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 468, 3, 18, 3, 93, 3, 18, 3, 58593,
```

The maximums appears on Line 2, Line 4, Line 8, Line 16 etc. each maximum is calculated

```
(5 * n) + 3, 292968 = (5 * 58593) + 3, 1464843 = (5 * 292968) + 3, 7324218 = (5 * 1464843) + 3, 36621093 = (5 * 7324218) + 3
```

**Base 6**

As with Base 3, 4 and 5, within base 6 counterfeit binary numbers greater that 1 always appear in pairs, e.g. 10, 11, then 100, 101 etc..
By counting the base 6 numbers that occur consecutively containing digits 2, 3, 4 and/or 5 we see a pattern emerge, e.g. 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4 etc.

This table shows (i) The first 39 base 6 numbers (0 - 38), (ii) The counterfeit binary numbers always appear in consecutive pairs, (iii) The start of the digit 2,3, 4 and/or 5 occurrence pattern.

```
Decimal     Counterfeit      Digit 2,3,4 & 5    Count
0                 0
1                 1
2                                    2
3                                    3
4                                    4
5                                    5            4
6                10
7                11
8                                   12
9                                   13
10                                  14
11                                  15
12                                  20
13                                  21
14                                  22
15                                  23
16                                  24
17                                  25
18                                  30
19                                  31
20                                  32
21                                  33
22                                  34
23                                  35
24                                  40
25                                  41
26                                  42
27                                  43
28                                  44
29                                  45
30                                  50
31                                  51
32                                  52
33                                  53
34                                  54
35                                  55            28
36             100
37             101
38                                 102
```

The base 6 pattern that's associated with the base 6 digits 2, 3, 4 and/or 5 occurrence pattern has a cycle of 32 and is as follows:-

```
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 37324,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 223948,
```

The numbers within each line have the following properties.
The lines contain both a horizontal and vertical pattern

**Horizontal Pattern**

All odd positions within each line are 4.

The even position maximum numbers are positioned at powers of 2 from left to right e.g.

```
Position     Maximum
    2           28
    4          172
    8         1036
   16         6220
   32        37324
```

The maximums are calculated

```
(6 * n) + 4, 28 = (6 * 4) + 4, 172 = (6 * 28) + 4, 1036 = (6 * 172) + 4, 6220 = (6 * 1036) + 4, 37324 = (6 * 6220) + 4
```

**Vertical Pattern**

The 32nd number in each line follows a cyclic pattern.

```
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 37324,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 223948,

4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 37324,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1343692,

4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 37324,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 223948,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 37324,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 8062156,

4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 37324,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 223948,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 37324,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1343692,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 37324,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 223948,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 37324,
4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 6220, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 1036, 4, 28, 4, 172, 4, 28, 4, 48372940,
```

The maximums appears on Line 2, Line 4, Line 8, Line 16 etc. each maximum is calculated

```
(6 * n) + 4, 223948 = (6 * 37324) + 4, 1343692 = (6 * 223948) + 4, 8062156 = (6 * 1343692) + 4, 48372940 = (6 * 8062156) + 4
```

Comment: According to that Numberphile video, the next number is not likely to exist!

Comment: Yes I understand that. This if an attempt to come up with a way to prove that it doesn'

Comment: @Hector you can get the heuristics to suggest so pretty quickly when represented as a binary number values that having it that have all 0's and 1's in base 4 for example have to have a hamming weight of at most $log_2(n)/2+1$ I think if I did the math correct. what are the density of the numbers of this form does it tend to 0 if so then relative to the whole of the natural numbers examples of it existing are extremely rare at very least.